# Will Ukrainian PoWs who took part in the referendum be punished in context of ukrainian threats?

Tags: armed-conflict, ukraine

As reported in some Russian sources, like [this one](https://ria.ru/20220924/referendum-1819236964.html?ysclid=l8mzmp75ri10469066) some Ukrainian PoWs took part in the referendum. Since Ukrainian government called the referendum illegal and a crime, do the PoWs who took part in the referendum still keep their status or are they now just traitors and criminals?

Here the translation of the article:

> **Ukrainian prisoners of war voted in the DPR referendum**
>
> About 300 Ukrainian prisoners of war voted in the DPR referendum
>
> DONETSK, 24 Sep - RIA Novosti. About 300 Ukrainian prisoners of war
> held in the colony in Yelenovka in the DPR voted in a referendum on
> joining the Russian Federation, Chairman of the People's Council of
> the DPR Vladimir Bidevka told RIA Novosti.
>
> "Today I was in Yelenovka (in the village there is a colony where
> Ukrainian prisoners of war are kept – ed.) with representatives of the
> election commission and international observers. The process of voting
> in the referendum was organized there for Ukrainian prisoners of war
> who had a registration mark in their documents on the territory of the
> DPR – the former Donetsk region and who expressed a desire to
> participate in the referendum. About 300 Ukrainian prisoners of war
> voted," Bidevka told RIA Novosti.

Acording to [this article](https://www.zerohedge.com/geopolitical/ukraine-threatens-5-year-prison-sentence-anyone-voting-sham-referendums):

> Ukraine Threatens 5-Year Prison Sentence **For Anyone** Voting In
> "Sham  Referendums"

For me the meaning of Anyone includes also people who was forced to, but posibly this is jus my wrong understanding of that word. So this question must be seen only in the context of the threat expresed by Ukraine.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Ukraine will ask Russian Federation to extradite their PoWs on the charges of voting in the referendum? Don't see why their status would change otherwise.

Comment: I think in case of POWs one can always question whether they did it on their own free will. If I am not mistaken, John McCain even participated in anti-American broadcasts while in the Vietnamese captivity - but still was hailed as a hero at home.

Comment: @Roger Vadim Shure once they are back to Ukraine they will all say that they were forced to no meter if true or not.

Comment: Maybe one could ask similar questions about the status of Russian POWs who have a law waiting back home to throw them in jail for surrendering, hmmm?  https://tass.com/politics/1512755

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica Be free to ask this question.

Answer (score 8):

[The criminal code of Ukraine says](https://sherloc.unodc.org/cld/uploads/res/document/ukr/2001/criminal-code-of-the-republic-of-ukraine-en_html/Ukraine_Criminal_Code_as_of_2010_EN.pdf):

> Article 40. Physical or mental coercion
>
> 1. A person's action or omission that caused harm to legally protected interests, is **not to be held a criminal offense**, where that person acted under direct physical coercion which
>    rendered him or her unable to be in control of his/her actions.

Aiden Aislin was forced to [sing the Russian national anthem](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2022/sep/25/aiden-aslin-release-russia-uk-ukraine) every morning while being POW. With such an information available, it should not be difficult to convince the Ukrainian law court that the prisoners voted under coercion.

Hence Ukrainian law does not foresee the criminal responsibility for the forced voting.

Answer (score 5):

The Center for Countering Disinformation at the National Security and Defense Council of Ukraine dismissed these reports as propaganda on September 25th in a post on [Telegram](https://t.me/CenterCounteringDisinformation/2702) (in Ukrainian).

> According to the propaganda media, 11 men and 23 women servicemen of
> the Armed Forces of Ukraine asked the militants to obtain passports of
> the "DPR" terrorist formation. Another 57 Ukrainian prisoners of war
> with residence in Donetsk region were forced to vote in a "referendum"
> for the region's accession to Russia.
>
> To give the provocation at least some plausibility, a note was made in
> the passports of the prisoners of war about the registration in the
> so-called DPR, which allegedly gave them the right to participate in
> the fake referendum.
>
> This is another manipulation aimed at promoting the Kremlin narrative
> in the occupied territories that "many of the captured Ukrainian
> military want to join the Russian Federation".

So it seems clear that the Ukrainian government blames Russia for intimidating the POWs into casting a vote in the referendum, in contravention of [Article 13 of the Geneva Convention  (III)](https://www.worldpress.org/specials/justice/Article_13.htm). It seems very unlikely, therefore, that they would seek to pursue criminal proceedings against a POW in the way you describe.